# How to prevent the user from purchasing the same IAP subscription across iOS and Mac?

Tags: ios, macos, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have been researching for a few days and haven't found a conclusive answer to my scenario.

- I would like to provide two subscription types on iOS: `Lite` and
  `Standard`.
- I would like to provide one subscription type on Mac:    `Standard`.

Standard is the bigger service that covers both iOS and Mac.
Lite is the lesser one that only supports iOS.

Based on what I see on AppStoreConnect, Mac has a complete separate IAP than iOS.  Hence I can't share the same `standard` subscription type among the two platforms. Even though the `standard` service is supposed to be cross-platform.

I can certainly store each receipt type from iOS and Mac into my DB separately and do the validations directly with AppStore and MacStore respectively.  But I can't stop the user from purchasing the `standard` subscription twice, once from iOS and then again from Mac.  This is really bad since I wouldn't be able to refund it either if someone makes this mistake since Apple regards them as two different apps.

Surely I can't be the only person with this problem, how is that supposed to be done, please?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't enforce this 100% on your end since they're separate apps in Apple land. So how is that supposed to be done? You need a subscription server that can track everything and don't allow users to purchase on Mac if they've bought on iPhone and vis versa. There's some good content on this blog that will help you think about what goes into building this out: https://www.revenuecat.com/2019/07/16/altconf-subscriptions-are-hard